# A lighter verb for "to preoccupy"

Tags: word-request

How can I express myself about a question that I think over  and that makes me wonder but the question is not serious and I want to imply I dont think about it all day or it is not big deal but the question is still in the back of my head.

Especially is there a phrasal verb which contains the word head.

For example :

> The question that professor asked in the class still ........ (my head).

Comment: The question can still be *rattling around* in your head (something you've been thinking about, off and on). The question can be *weighing on* you (more serious, vexing, troubling).

Comment: @TRomano how about "the question has been bugging me for the last  few days"

Comment: "rattling around in my head" refers to something you've been thinking about, intermittently, such as an idea, and "bugging me" refers to something which has been *troubling* or *vexing* you a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One <del>The only</del> word I can think of is "haunts" and that would normally relate to negative or undesirable occurrences. Used in the style *"The {{some occurrence}} still haunts me."*  So, for your example, *"The question that [the] professor asked in the class still haunts me."*

Another word is "reminisce" which has the meaning *"to talk or write about past experiences that you remember with pleasure"*, see [the Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reminisce). However, "reminisce" cannot be used in the position (i.e. final word of the sentence) desired in the question. It can be used in the style *"I [or we] often reminisce about {{some happy event}}"*. E.g. *"My wife and I enjoy reminiscing about our first holiday together"*.

Other forms of the sentence may be better. You could say *"My thoughts often return to {{some occurrence}}"*. E.g. *"My thoughts often return to the good old days when petrol (gas) was cheap"*. Or *"I often think about {{some occurrence}}*". For a positive example *"I often think about my good fortune where answering the question that the professor asked in the class led to a wonderful career."*

Comment: Thank you. How about " to scatch my head" ? I heard " to haunt" but as you said it has a connotation of something burdensome or negative.

Comment: "Scratch my head" relates to trying to solve a puzzle or a problem (in addition to the obvious meaning of dealing with a itch).

Comment: It sounds like it is close to what I mean actually. How about " to pore over" ?  Would I be too stretching if I said " I have been poring over how to pay the bills becuase I am out of work now"  or about a puzzle or problem , or  "poring over" needs to involve something that should be read.

Comment: Perhaps you want *"My thoughts often return to the question that the professor asked in class"*. To "pore over" means to study carefully. For the "bill" sentence, you cannot pore over a "how", you can pore over books or papers. You might *"... pore over ideas on how to pay bills ..."*

Comment: Yes, Thank you again ..my thoughts often return to question that what the alternative  verb for to preoccupy is.